# data-animation effects not working in codeigniter php

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Hi i have used bootstrap carousel in my website.I have used data animation effects for moving texts from right to left from up and down and for image animation effects.But the data animation effects is not working in codeigniter php.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <!-- First slide -->
        <div class="item active ">
            <h3 class="heading82">OPEN SOURCE <span class="heading81">C</span>ONTENT <span class="heading81">M</span>ANAGEMENT <span class="heading81">S</span>YSTEMS</h3> 
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/3_1 (4).png" class="heading84"><h3 class="heading83">complete control over the content of the website from personalized admin panel</h3><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/4_2 (4).png" class="heading85">
            <div class="captions">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/z2.png" class="heading94" data-animation="animated bounceInRight">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/z1.png" class="heading95" data-animation="animated bounceInRight">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/z.png" class="heading95" data-animation="animated bounceInRight">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/z3 (3).png" class="heading96" data-animation="animated bounceInRight">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-caption" >
                <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown" class="heading86">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/5.png" class="heading87">&nbsp;Easy edit, delete and create new content
                </h3>
                <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown" class="heading88">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/5.png" class="heading89">&nbsp;Manage your own online store with little or zero technical expertise
                </h3>
                <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown" class="heading90">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/5.png" class="heading91">&nbsp;Convert your traffic into customers
                </h3>
                <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown" class="heading92">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/5.png" class="heading93">&nbsp;Custom Design templates to manage your blogs
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /.item -->

        <!-- Second slide -->
        <div class="item ">
        <h3 class="heading43">FULLY <span class="heading41">R</span>ESPONSIVE & <span class="heading41">SEO</span> OPTIMIZED <span class="heading41">W</span>EBSITE <span class="heading41">D</span>ESIGN</h3> 
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/1 (2).png" class="heading45"><h3 class="heading44">Optimal viewing experience with easy reading and navigation on different mobiles & tablets</h3><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/2 (2).png" class="heading42">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInLeft" class="heading46">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/5.png" class="heading47">&nbsp;We design custom build high impact site that attracts your target audience
                </h3>
                <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInLeft" class="heading48">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/5.png" class="heading49">&nbsp;Ultra Responsive Design using HTML & CSS3
                </h3>

                <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInLeft" class="heading50">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/5.png" class="heading51">&nbsp;100% compatibility in all mobile devices and browsers 
                </h3>
                <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInLeft" class="heading52">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/slider/5.png" class="heading53">&nbsp;We build scalable and smarter business solutions 
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.item -->



    </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Comment: Hi can anyone sort out this

Comment: It will probably be some sort of js problem with dependencies not being properly loaded... Can you provide live link?

Comment: @AdamK. its staging.teknotrait.com

Comment: Try to wrap contents of demo.js like this `(function( $ ) {
$(document).ready(function(){/*CONTENTS*/
});
})(jQuery);`
To make sure you initialize carousel after HTML DOM is fully rendered and dependencies are loaded.

Comment: @AdamK. i am not getting you what you are saying

Comment: @AdamK. i changed demo.js according to that but it is not working